# R Solver for combinations

Tags: r, combinations, solver

I have a data frame which contains decimal numbers in 5 columns. Try to think it as an excel file. For every column I find the sum. I provide an example below:

[image]

The problem is that I want to keep the optimal lines/observations that they will:

- Have individual sum as much closer to 0 - for the col1, col2 and col3
- **AND simultaneously** the col4 and col5 to sum (again individually) the closer to (let's say 3).

The example has created with a random sample, so it does not contain negative numbers, but I provided it as an example.

I think that problems of this case are solved via a Solver in R. I would like to find a code that solves the above problem.

Comment: Could you show what you've tried please, and post your data as a reproducible example.

Comment: @RussHyde I have not tried something yet, because I am not so familiar with the solvers.

Answer (score 2):

I used before the package lpSolve with the function lp to solve linear programming problems with constraints. It will be easy to set up as you don't appear to have many  constraints. However, because it is a single objective function, you need to define the objective function probably as the minimum difference of the sum of your 2 branches (read: Cols 1 to 3, and Cols 4 to 5).

Potentially there would be other methods but this one should be rather easy.

Hopefully this will help.

Regards

Comment: Do you have any example, on how can I define the above constraints in the lpsolver?

Comment: Please see the comment below by @Erwin-Kalvelagen, he does a great formulation of the model.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two obvious ways of doing this.

I'll write down the mathematical models that make more formal my interpretation of your problem.

### Quadratic Formulation

The first is a **least squares** approach. Let

```
x(i) = 1 if row i is selected
       0 otherwise
```

Then we can write:

```
min sum(j, w(j)*d(j)^2)
    d(j) = sum(i, a(i,j)*x(i)) - t(j)
    d(j) : free variable (can be substituted out if wanted)
```

where

```
    t(j) : target sum for column j (0 and 3 in your example)
    w(j) : weight for column j  (choose 1 if there is no good reason to use something else)
    a(i,j) : your data matrix (or data frame)
```

This is called a MIQP model (Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming). There are MIQP solvers available for R.

### Linear Formulation

Instead of **least squares** we can choose to use **least absolute deviations**. A high-level model can look like:

```
min sum(j, w(j)*|d(j)|)
    d(j) = sum(i, a(i,j)*x(i)) - t(j)
    d(j) : free variable (can be substituted out if wanted)
```

To make this a proper MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) model we need to make everything linear. One possible formulation is:

```
min sum(j, w(j)*y(j))
    d(j) = sum(i, a(i,j)*x(i)) - t(j)
    -y(j) <= d(j) <= y(j)  (we can write this as two inequalities)
    d(j) : free variable 
    y(j) >= 0  (positive variable)
```

There are many MIP solvers available for use with R.

Comment: The constraints are that in columns (1 and 2 and 3 individually) I want to have the 3 sums 0<=sum<=1 and simultaneously the columns 4 & 5 (again the individual sums per column) > 1. Could you provide an example of how to define these constraints in an R solver? Thanks.